# Kendo grid read datasource with http post response

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new at Kendo UI, I was using datatables to show values,here is my old code (Working):

```
$http.post("/reports/api/g3swmf/report", $scope.g3sWmf ).success(function(data){
    $scope.reportVal += " - " + data;
}).then(function (response){
    $scope.items=response.data;   
}
```

And here is Kendo UI version (not Working):

```
$scope.g3sGridOptions = {
    toolbar: ["excel"],
    excel: {
        allPages: true
    },
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
        read: {
            url:("/reports/api/g3swmf/report", $scope.g3sWmf ),
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                poloCode: { type: "string" },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define not working

Comment: cant reach the /reports/api/g3swmf/report controller and get response data @The_Black_Smurf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kendo's transport url is suppose to be a string.

```
url:"/reports/api/g3swmf/report"
```

It doesn't handle the same the `$http.post` does.  In fact, it pass the read parameter directly to jquery.ajax.

There's 2 way to solve this.

1. Use a string url for your transport
2. Define your transport.read as a function.  You'll then be able to call you're own `$http.post`.  If you define a function, note that kendo will provide a event parameter with some callback methods that should be used to send the data back to the grid.

Here's a custom read example:

```
read: function (readOptions) {
    $http.post("/reports/api/g3swmf/report", $scope.g3sWmf ).success(function(data){
        readOptions.success(data);
    })
}
```

Please refer to [kendo dataSource API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read) for more details